# How to change icon on Google map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to use my customize icon on Google map, and added icon url on the code. But it's still not reflecting on the map. Can anyone suggest, what i am missing here. Why icon is not changing, after adding the icon url "http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/sailboat-tourism.png".

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var markers = [
            {
            "title": 'This is title',
        "lat": '-37.801578',
            "lng": '145.060508',
        "icon": 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/sailboat-tourism.png',
            "description": 'Vikash Rathee. <strong> This is test Description</strong> <br/><a href="http://www.pricingindia.in/pincode.aspx">Pin Code by 

City</a>'

        }
];
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
        flat: true,
        styles: [ { "stylers": [ { "hue": "#4bd6bf" }, { "gamma": "1.58" } ] } ],
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
</script>


<div id="dvMap" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 29):

we can change the icon of markers, i did it on right click event.
Lets see if it works for you...

```
// Create a Marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    title:'Sample Tool Tip'
  });


// Set Icon on any event
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "rightclick", function() {
        marker.setIcon('blank.png'); // set image path here...
});
```

Comment: `marker.setIcon()` is key to changing the icon after it has been displayed on the map

Answer (score 17):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: 'your-icon.png'
});
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
var locations = [
        ['San Francisco: Power Outage', 37.7749295, -122.4194155,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png'],
        ['Sausalito', 37.8590937, -122.4852507,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'],
        ['Sacramento', 38.5815719, -121.4943996,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'],
        ['Soledad', 36.424687, -121.3263187,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'],
        ['Shingletown', 40.4923784, -121.8891586,'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png']
    ];



//inside the loop
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon: locations[i][3]
            });
```

Comment: Manish, Did not working. Can you please post the complete code or demo on fiddle or cssdeck?

Comment: marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:myLatlng ,
                map: map,
                icon: locations[0][3]
            }); check this get first image icon from array.

Comment: Not working Manish. Could you please post your suggested working code somewhere on fiddle or cssdeck.com or email me : vicky.rathee2005@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(23.016427,72.571156),
                map: map,
                icon: 'images/map_marker_icon.png',
                title: 'Hi..!'
            });
```

apply local path on icon only

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the targeted map :

```
var markers = [
            {
            "title": 'This is title',
            "lat": '-37.801578',
            "lng": '145.060508',
            "map":  map,
            "icon": 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/sailboat-tourism.png',
            "description": 'Vikash Rathee. <strong> This is test Description</strong> <br/><a href="http://www.pricingindia.in/pincode.aspx">Pin Code by 

City</a>'
            }
];
```

Comment: EdenSource, Did not working. Can you please post the complete code or demo on fiddle or cssdeck?

Comment: icon: markers[i][3], is probably wrong. Replace it with "icon": 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/sailboat-tourism.png',

Answer (score 1):

Manish, Eden after your suggestion:  here is the code. But still showing the red(Default) icon.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var markers = [
            {
            "title": 'This is title',
            "lat": '-37.801578',
            "lng": '145.060508',
        "icon": 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_green.png',
            "description": 'Vikash Rathee. <br/><a href="http://www.pricingindia.in/pincode.aspx">Pin Code by City</a>'
        }
];
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
            flat: true,
            styles: [ { "stylers": [ { "hue": "#4bd6bf" }, { "gamma": "1.58" } ] } ],
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
        icon: markers[i][3],
                title: data.title
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
</script>


<div id="dvMap" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
</div>
```