# add custom icons to google maps nearby places part2

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

got my current location with nearby places eg.(grocery_or_supermarket) and their icons.

but what i want to do is give each of the shops their own logo as an icon.

I'm new to JS so any help plz!

I have code to share if needed.

```
 <script>
    var infowindow,
     placemarkers = [];
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    var icons = {
        parking: {
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
        },
        library: {
            icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
        },
        info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
        },
        grocery_or_supermarket: {
            icon: iconBase + 'convenience.png'
        }
    };

    function placeSearch(map, request) {
        var map = map;
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.search(request,

        function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                    bounds.extend(results[i].geometry.location);
                    placemarkers.push(createMarker(results[i].geometry.location,
                    map,
                    icons['grocery_or_supermarket'].icon,
                    results[i].name,
                    false, {
                        fnc: function () {
                            infowindow.open();
                        }

                    }));
                }
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            }
        });

    }

    function createMarker(latlng, map, icon, content, center, action) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: latlng,
            content: content
        });
        ////////toggle bounce////
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);

        function toggleBounce() {

            if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            } else {
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);   } } ///////bounce end////

        if (icon) {
            marker.setIcon(icon);
        }

        if (center) {
            map.setCenter(latlng);
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(this.content);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

        if (action) {
            action.fnc(map, action.args);
        }
        return marker;
    }

    function initialize() {

        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316),
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: location,
                zoom: 15,
            });


        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (place) {
            createMarker(
            new google.maps.LatLng(place.coords.latitude,
            place.coords.longitude),
            map,
            null,
                'your current position',
            true, {
                fnc: placeSearch,
                args: {
                    radius: 5000,
                    types: ['grocery_or_supermarket'],
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(place.coords.latitude,
                    place.coords.longitude)
                }
            });
        });
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: `I have code to share if needed.`  Please do (in the question itself).

Comment: If you want a different logo for each location you will need a database with each location and each logo uri.

Comment: or maybe i can add logos for each info window of the locations?

Comment: You can do whichever you want (use a logo for the icon or add the logo into the infowindow).  But you need to have some way of determining which logo to use with which marker (as TrevorBrooks commented).

Comment: okay cool thanks guys...
ill get back to this post as soon as i have a solution, and share the research.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do with not so much code:

```
var iconBase = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: iconBase + 'myMarker.png' // Set yourt marker here
});
```

Here's is more about google maps and icons.
https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

Almost the same question, maybe can help you: 
[How to change icon on Google map marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245800/how-to-change-icon-on-google-map-marker)

Comment: yes, but how to give each of the location points their own icon when they are the same type?

Comment: This does not address his question.